# Editing a list of strings through custom inspector is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a voice line + subtitle system, using a custom inspector to make it easier to use.
All is working perfectly until i tried to show a subtitle EditorGUILayout.TextField similar to how I am using EditorGUILayout.ObjectField for the voice audio clips.
This works (No subtitle functions):

```
showAudioClipList = EditorGUILayout.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup(showAudioClipList, new GUIContent("Audio Clips", "Audio clips available to play when interacting with this object."));
if (showAudioClipList)
{
    GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
    for (int i = 0; i < _AudioClips.arraySize; i++)
    {
        SerializedProperty AC_ref = _AudioClips.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal("box");
        AC_ref.objectReferenceValue = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Clip " + (i + 1) + ":", AC_ref.objectReferenceValue, typeof(AudioClip), false);
        if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("X", "Remove this clip"), GUILayout.MaxWidth(20)))
            t.AudioClips.RemoveAt(i);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }

    EditorGUILayout.Space();
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Add Clip", "Add new clip entry")))
        t.AudioClips.Add(null);
    if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Remove All Clips", "Remove all clip entries")))
        t.AudioClips.Clear();
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
}
EditorGUILayout.EndFoldoutHeaderGroup();
```

I want to make it show a text field underneath each audioclip box so I can write in subtitles for each voice line. I got it working for a non-list string, but cant get it working for a list of strings in the same way that the list of AudioClips works.

I've tried
`t.Subtitles[i] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(etc...`
and
`ST_ref.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextField(etc...` trying to replicate how the audioclip one works, plus some others, but all cause errors in console and collapse the inspector.

Can you understand my problem from just this code?

Comment: surely you make a list of a structure of clip + description? I know odin makes an easy job of this, but surely that then works

Comment: @BugFinder I think I know how to do that, but is there a simpler way to add it to the current setup, rather than redoing it like that?

Comment: possibly but I think it would be a lot of work

Comment: What error does adding `t.Subtitles[i] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(etc...` result in?

Comment: @AleksandrStepanov Writing `t.Subtitles[i] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(new GUIContent("Subtitle:"), t.Subtitles[i]);` gives error `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.` and it also collapses the component in the inspector to be completely unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
I'm using

```
SerializedProperty SC_ref = _Subtitles.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
```

(*goes under the `SerializedProperty AC_ref = _AudioClips.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);`*)in the same way as the audio clips, and

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(SC_ref);
```

(*goes at the bottom of the FOR loop inside, in its own BeginHorizontal("box")*) to show, set, and save each string value as each is displayed under its corresponding AudioClip object. EditorGUILayout.PropertyField saves changes at the same time as showing the variable in inspector, so it only needs that short code line to work.
`_Subtitles` is a SerializedProperty of a List, and by using `GetArrayElementAtIndex()` I can specify a specific entry in the list to modify by temporarily saving it as its own SerializedProperty.